# Redirecting to other page using php via URL

Tags: php, http, redirect

Here's my php code

```
 <?php
    $s = $_POST['s'];
    header("Location: " . $s);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Is it possible to execute this code using a url?
I tried mywebsite.com/code.php?s=www.google.com

but it doesn't redirect me to google.

Comment: Are you sure about the POST? ... The example URL looks more like a GET.

Comment: and you probably need to pass schema (`http` or `https`) in order to be redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variables on the querystring of a URL are accessible via `$_GET`. (`$_POST` can be used to access form fields in the body of a request.)

Therefore

```
$s = $_GET['s'];
```

should work for you.

Comment: that solved it!. I tried the GET at first, it looks like i just mistype it as $GET_['s'] instead of $_GET['s']. Thanks :D